# Magento 2: How to rearrange sales order view in adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, orders, adminhtml

I want to rearrange the sections in the sales order view (which is displayed while viewing an order in admin page).

I tried to move the **Items ordered** section before **Order & Account Information**. To achieve this, I have added `sales_order_view.xml` in my backend theme in `Magento_Sales/layout`.

```
<page>
    <body>
        <move element="order_items" destination="order_tab_info" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, the sales order view stays unchanged. I also tried to remove the `order_items` block which did work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot able to move `order_items` through layout file. Since `order_tab_info` block not renders it's child blocks automatically. So even though moving the blocks inside the `order_tab_info` block from the layout results in the same structure.

To do so, override `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml` and move the items ordered block before Line no:19 `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>`

```
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items Ordered') ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getItemsHtml() ?>
</section>
```

Now the items ordered block will be loaded before Order information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'd hoped that there would be a possibility via the layout file. I think in this case Magento is very inconsistent.Especially because I have to change two phtml files to be able to change the order for this single page.